# Read and save image use for loop in C++ with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I use `for` loop to read images from a file, the name of the image is like '1.jpg', '2.jpg'. I want to save them to another file but fail to do that, the bool check always false.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    string img_name = std::to_string(V[i].second) + ".jpg";// '1.jpg'
    Mat similars = imread("..\\image.orig\\" + img_name);
    bool check = imwrite("..\\Desktop\\saveimage\\" + img_name, similars);
}
```

Please, see this and tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Probably path is wrong cos of that cant reach the images. U should check image is valid or not before writing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a path rather than Desktop, sometimes the system doesn't give permission to applications to do so.